# Postgres query between two timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to request a list of 'path' between a date range.

My DB is laid out like this:

```
create table mydb 
(
machine varchar(9),
path varchar(350),
in_date timestamp
);
```

I insert data like so:

```
machine   | path                     | in_date
------------------------------------------------------------
nodea     | /var/log/log1            | 2014-03-01 00:29:08
nodeb     | /var/log/log1            | 2014-03-01 00:14:13
nodea     | /var/log/log2            | 2014-03-02 00:11:11
nodeb     | /var/log/log2            | 2014-03-02 01:10:10
nodea     | /var/log/log2            | 2014-03-03 00:31:31
nodea     | /var/log/log3            | 2014-03-04 19:55:12
```

What I want to pull is a list for all of the 'path' entries for nodea between two dates.
I have tried:

```
 select path from mydb where machine = 'nodea' and in_date between '2014-03-01 00:29:08' and '2014-03-03 00:31:31';
 select path from mydb where machine = 'nodea' and in_date >= '2014-03-01 00:29:08' and in_date <= '2014-03-03 00:31:31';
```

Neither of these seem to work, or they may work in a method I am not expecting and return 0 rows.

How do I query to pull a list between the selected dates and get something like:

```
path
-------------------------------
/var/log/log1
/var/log/log2
/var/log/log2
```

Tnx.

Comment: Both your solutions seem to be working. See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6ac7/1). Which begs the question - what are you doing wrong? Is `select path from mydb where machine='nodea'` working properly? How about `select path from mydb where in_date between '2014-03-01 00:29:08' and '2014-03-03 00:31:31'`?

Comment: Wild guess, you have timestamps without timezone. Is there some setting you have made somewhere that makes these inconsistent between the literals in the query and the column?

Comment: Thanks guys - a query of `select path from mydb where machine = 'nodea';` does work properly, but `select path from mydb where in_date between '2014-03-01 00:29:08' and '2014-03-03 00:31:31';` does not. I suspect you may be correct about the timezone. I believe the timestamp is fed `Fri Jul 12 11:35:15 2013` but I'll need to go back and check the script which populates the data. If it does insert data in such a format, would there be a suggestion on a query type or change in the DB to make this more sane?

Comment: The DB is indeed fed this way: `Thu Feb  6 01:02:57 2014`

Comment: Use the `timestamptz` (A.K.A. `timestamp with time zone`) datatype instead of just `timestamp` (A.K.A. `timestamp without time zone`) to avoid such problems with timezone.

Comment: The script which populates the data does not pass the timezone - why would I need to use timestamptz in this instance?

Comment: @user3389883, it doesn't matter if it pass or not, `timestamptz` is more about how it is stored in the database. Although you should configure the `TimeZone` parameter as the same that you are using.

Comment: Thanks MatheusOI - that nudged me to a workable solution. I converted to timestamptz and modified my php code to strip off the last 3 chars (timezone offset).